# tracking position/location in test keyboard & mouse mode (not ppt) with new vizconnect

Tags: vizard

I can track location fine pre - vizconnect using code like this:-

```
vrpn7 = viz.add('vrpn7.dle')
posTracker = vrpn7.addTracker('PPT0@WorldViz-PC', 0 )
```

and then

```
x,y,z = posTracker.getPosition()
```

but I now use the new vizconnect e.g.

```
vizconnect.go( 'vizconnect_hmd_ppt.py' )
```

I'm wondering what the recommended way is to then access the trackers from my main project '.py' file and particularly when I'm using a keyboard/mouse scenario to simulate movement for during program development.

Any advice would be most welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it was pretty straightforward:

first check the names of the trackers using:

```
print(  vizconnect.getTrackerDict() )
```

it may return something like this

> 'mouse_and_keyboard_walking'

along with some others e.g. inertia cube, then do

```
gTracker = vizconnect.getTracker( 'mouse_and_keyboard_walking' )
```

or

```
gTracker = vizconnect.getTracker( 'PPT0@WorldViz-PC' )
```

then periodically call (probably on a callback() ):-

```
x, y, z = gTracker.getPosition()
```